# c#: convertir caracter a entero

Tags: c#, cast

tengo el siguiente [ejercicio](https://www.codewars.com/kata/disarium-number-special-numbers-series-number-3/train/csharp):

```
using System;

class Kata
{
    public static string DisariumNumber(int number)
    {
        var a = $"{number}".ToCharArray();
        double sum =0;

        for(int i = 0, pot = 1; i< a.Length; i++, pot++){
          sum += Math.Pow(Int32.Parse(a[i]),pot);
        }

        return ((double)number) == sum ? "Disarium !!" : "Not !!";
    }
}
```

Pero me produce el error

> src/Solution.cs(11,39): error CS1503: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'char' to 'System.ReadOnlySpan'

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo para que funcione la conversión?

Comment: Supongo que el problema lo tienes en `Int32.Parse(a[i])`.  `Int32.Parse` espera como argumento un string, y le estas pasando un char. Prueba con `Int32.Parse(a[i].ToString)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba esto:

```
Convert.ToInt32(a[i])-48
```

- [Convert.ToInt32(char)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_Char_) the convierte el carácter a su equivalente numérico en Unicode (o lo que es lo mismo para números, a su equivalente ASCII).
- Le restas 48 que es el código Unicode/ASCII del carácter '0', y dado que los caracteres numéricos tienen códigos consecutivos, ya lo tienes.

Comment: Gracias, ya lo había pasado mediente `sum += Math.Pow(a[i]- '0',pot);` saludos